# How to use node js json web token library in core php application

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-web-token

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jws/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js"></script>
<script>
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
</script>
```

Code done like above but still we are getting following errors.

Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/sign-stream" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
Uncaught Error: Module name "jws" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
Uncaught Error: Module name "jsonwebtoken" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is not Node.js specific you can use it with a lot of languages for php use [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

Comment: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken : this node js library for json web token, we have to use this for our application to extract the jwt token

Comment: but if you are writing your code in PHP then why are you using a node module?

Comment: use native php module rather than using nodejs module

Comment: If we use this node js library, can decode the data client side itself. purpose is avoiding server side call

Comment: you are not suppose to decode it client side it is made to be decoded server side if you decode client side then anyone with an browser dev-tool can just see your secret-key and generate tokens for themselves you need to get your concept of jwt straight. see : https://jwt.io/introduction/